# RabbitMQ Connect/Disconnect Notifications

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and I am working on an application that will receive information from many devices and route all messages into a couple of queues depending on the MQTT topic.  I was able to get all of this working easily, but now I am looking into how to push a message to a queue when a client connects or disconnects from RabbitMQ in order to update the current status of the client in my database.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: RabbitMQ does not do this, if that's what you're asking. You could certainly write your own routine that accomplishes this, though.

Comment: @theMayer: : can you help to make the first steps to implement it ? Does it have to be written in Erlang ?

Comment: Have the client publish a message when it connects.

Answer (score 2):

[Event Exchange Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html)

*Client connection, channels, queues, consumers, and other parts of the system naturally generate events. For example, when a connection is accepted, authenticated and access to the target virtual host is authorised, it will emit an event of type connection_created. When a connection is closed or fails for any reason, a connection_closed event is deleted.*

Unfortunately the rabbitmq_event_exchange is created after importing bindings from definition.json. Which means that the  `amq.rabbitmq.event` cannot be bound to a queue via the configuration and must be bound after the start.